# MySql AES_ENCRYPT 256 encryption

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to use mysql AES_ENCRYPT with 256 bit encryption but dont know how to configure mysql, can anybody help so that i can use AES 256, i am using xampp.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//encryption-functions.html first result when you google it